# How to set imageView as rounded shape without image loader library?

Tags: android

Android, I want to set an imageView(xml) in rounded shape (as we create shape.xml for button and textView etc.) so that when we set an image to thi imageView it automatically display as rounded shape.

Comment: there are many custom libraries available. they are very easy to use. this is one of my fav for circular imageview https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: hi Hirak, Thanks for your comment, but this is not what i want. i have seen in an earlier project, where they used two image view one above another and in first they set an png image which was a circle from inside and transparent from inside the circle. i want something like that

Comment: i don't remember what they did exactly